# Why single char and "single char String" not equal when converted to long (.toLong())

Tags: kotlin, tostring, long-integer

I wanted to sum the digits of `Long` variable and add it to the variable it self, I came with the next **working** code:

```
private fun Long.sumDigits(): Long {
    var n = this
    this.toString().forEach { n += it.toString().toLong() }
    return n
}
```

Usage: `assert(48.toLong() == 42.toLong().sumDigits())`

I had to use `it.toString()` in order to get it work, so I came with the next test and I don't get it's results:

```
@Test
fun toLongEquality() {
    println("'4' as Long = " + '4'.toLong())
    println("\"4\" as Long = " + "4".toLong())
    println("\"42\" as Long = " + "42".toLong())

    assert('4'.toString().toLong() == 4.toLong())
}
```

Output:

```
'4' as Long = 52
"4" as Long = 4
"42" as Long = 42
```

Is it a good practice to use `char.toString().toLong()` or there is a better way to convert `char` to `Long`?

Does `"4"` represented by `char`s? Why it is not equal to it `char` representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> class Char : Comparable (source) Represents a 16-bit Unicode
>   character. On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are
>   represented as values of the primitive type char.
>
> fun toLong(): Long
>
> Returns the value of this character as a Long.

When you use `'4' as Long` you actually get the Unicode (ASCII) code of the char '4'

Answer (score 2):

As mTak says, Char represents a Unicode value. If you are using Kotlin on the JVM, you can define your function as follows:

```
private fun Long.sumDigits() = this.toString().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum().toLong()
```

There's no reason to return `Long` rather than `Int`, but I've kept it the same as in your question.

Non-JVM versions of Kotlin don't have the `Character` class; use `map {it - '0'}` instead.

Comment: OP wants the function to return the sum of the digits plus the number itself. Just add `this + this.toString().............`